# How to Call Custom .dll in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying add new function inside my SharePoint and I created HTML code and it will call .dll file where I download it. However, when I run project standalone outside SharePoint it works. However, inside SharePoint code (HTML) when I add assembly to my .dll , it shows not found.
I tried adding it in SafeControl in web.config bug still same issue.
I place .dll in all places where other SharePoint .dll are there but still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood what you trying to accomplish but I suspect you are using some SharePoint on-prem and you deploy some kind of solution (webpart or other) to a site were you want to use an external dll. If that is the case you need to create some kind of empty sharepoint farm project (or use one of the existing farm solutions) and add an external dll to it so it will be deployed to GAC. When an dll is in Global Assembly Cache then we may use it in all places in SharePoint.
Here I found [some blog post how to add a external dll to GAC](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/add-external-dll-with-sharepoint-wsp-to-gac)

I hope this will be of any help

Answer (score 0):

When the project is running inside the SP server, it's different from when it's starting outside the farm. You need to ensure the dll has been copied to gac, or the server cannot find it.

If you're developing a custom WCF in SP on-premise, you may take a reference of below demo:

- [Custom WCF](https://github.com/kongmengfei/sharedproject/blob/master/Barkes.SP13.WCF.PresidentsServiceSample_source/Barkes.Services.Presidents/ISAPI/BarkesServices/PresidentsService.svc.cs)

More reference:

- https://blog.mastykarz.nl/including-additional-assemblies-wsp-visual-studio-sharepoint-development-tools/

BR